# When "any" (whatever) is followed by a countable noun, does the noun need to be plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, some-any

This is an extract from a formal certificate written by a non-native English speaker.

> This certification is issued to the bearer for any possible *uses*.

Is it correct? Personally, I think it should be "*use*". (I also appreciate a rephrase that can convey this message better and clearer.)

Comment: There's nothing grammatically wrong with the plural *uses*.  The problem is that the statement is meaningless.  It says the certification may be used for any purpose that the certification is for.  What does that add?

Comment: It is arguable that the 'use' in 'any use' could be considered non-count rather than singular count. Compare 'Is this any use? / Is this of any possible use? /  'These are no use.'

Comment: I think the idiomatic expression would be "for *all* possible uses"

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. In the following sentences, the use of the plural depends on the structure.

Any person who trespasses is liable to a fine not exceeding forty shillings.
Any people who trespass are liable to a fine not exceeding forty shillings.

Without a relative clause after and after a preposition, the choice is mostly stylistic.

Comment: So, you are saying that either way is correct. It just comes down to a matter of writer's style or preference, right?

Comment: Well if the certification allows the bearer any number of uses, then the plural is preferable. If however it only allows any use, but only one, then you might wanna use the singular.

Comment: That's a better answer; if there's one possible use, then use the singular. Else, if there is more than one possible use, use the plural.